# How to chain nested promises containing then and catch blocks?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

How to chain `ES6` nested `Promises` with each `Promise` in the nesting having `then` and `catch` blocks?

For example, what will be the `Promise` `then` and `catch` blocks chaining implementation equivalent for following nested `AJAX` calls implementation handled by `success` and `error` callbacks, considering every API call returns a `Promise`?

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'url1', 
    success: function() {
        console.log('URL1 call success');
        $.ajax({    
            url: 'url2',
            success: function() {
                console.log('URL2 call success');
            },
            error:function() {
                console.log('URL2 call error');
            }
         })
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('URL1 call error');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url3',
            success: function() {
                console.log('URL3 call success');
            },
            error:function() {
                console.log('URL3 call error');
            }
         })
    }})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to chain promises, you can have each handler return a promise, and then chain the `then` and `catch` functions from there. I believe this demonstrates what you're looking to do:

```js
const getPromise = (time, reject=false) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject ? rej() : res('done'), time);
});

getPromise(500)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('first response');
    return getPromise(500, false);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('second response');
    return getPromise(500, true);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('you can have catch statements return promises, too');
    return getPromise(700, true)
  })
  .then(() => {
    // this structure falls down here; is this a response to the promise returned from
    // the catch, or the promise returned from the 'second response' part?
    console.log('third response');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.error('hit an error');
  });
```

However, it's important to realise that this is a chain with no branching logic. With the structure `handle success` -> `handle error` -> `handle success`, once your error handlers return valid promises, the remainder of the chain cannot tell whether what came before was a result of the success or error handlers. There's no branching logic here and you need nesting of promises to achieve that.

There are two main alternatives here. First you could throw different error types and handle each different error in a single `catch` handler. Second, you could use `async`/`await` syntax instead. Either may work for you but I think that they'd warrant a separate question.

Comment: Here the last catch block is common to all preceding then blocks, I guess. But that is not what I am required. I need each Promise in the nesting have there own individual then and catch block pair. Here, I think only then blocks chained are respective to their Promises but not catch block. Having Individual catch block will help if we have different error handling for each Promise in the nesting.

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari Then it sounds as though you're describing behavior that is inherently nested; perhaps if you could give an example of what the syntax to describe such a chain would look like, then we might be able to this of ways to make that possible

Comment: Please refer to the snippet mentioned in the question. I have logged messages in the success and error callbacks to identify which API call has been succeeded or failed. I want to know how to achieve the same with Promises. And for example of chaining syntax, you can refer to the snippet posted by you. There I need have each then block its own catch block, so it can be recognized exactly which Promise is rejected in the chain. For example, I guess there would same number of catch blocks as of then blocks with logs like, 'first error', 'second error', ... Just need to know how to chain them.

Comment: I have seen the snippet but aside from saying "you put the new api call which returns a promise in the `then`/`catch` statement" there's not much more to say. You can't have a chain of promises which have branching logic like your example above without putting the subsequent calls in the `then`/`catch` statement

Comment: It means if we have to put API calls in then and catch blocks then the structure will be like a callback hell. It will be exactly opposite in nature of Promise as Promise are used to avoid callback hell caused by callback functions structure, right?

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari I've updated my answer to do what I _think_ you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

`This can be written like this :`

```
function makeAjaxCall(url){
    return new Promise((s, f) => {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: url, 
            success: s,
            error: f
        })
    })
}
makeAjaxCall('url1')
.then((data) => {
    console.log('URL1 call success');
    return makeAjaxCall('url2')
}, (error) => {
    console.log('URL1 call error');
    return makeAjaxCall('url3')
})
.then(() => {
    //It Could be Either url2 success or url3 success
}, () => {
    //It Could be Either url2 failure or url3 falure
})
```

Comment: But here the last then and catch block loses context for which Promise they are belonging. What if we have different implementation for resolved and reject of each Promise in the nesting and so need to have exclusive pair of then and catch blocks for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `.done` and `.fail` ?

You can re-write the code as below

```js
const doAjaxCall = (url) => $.ajax({ url })

const callURL = (url) => doAjaxCall(url)
  .done(() => console.log(`${url} is ok!`) )
  .fail(() => console.log(`${url} failed!`) );

doAjaxCall('/url1')
.done(() => {
  console.log('url1 is ok!');
  callURL('/url2');
 })
.fail(callURL('url3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for solution in ES6 implemetion of Promises